# How to disable back start, search button in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app in 8.1. app have a requirement to deactivate the three button click once app is launched. i.e Back button, Start button and Search button. Please suggest the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable `start` and `search` button . But you can manage `back` button taps if your app is in foreground.

You can use `BackPressed`  event to manage back button taps . Use the below code to subscribe to the event.

```
 HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

event handler

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{      
        e.Handled = true;  // this will cancel the navigation         
}
```

You can find more info from [here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/tips/general-tips/handling-the-back-button-in-a-windows-phone-8-1-app/)

Comment: I agree about back button . But can we solve this issue with kiosk mode in windows phone